# Channel overlapping vs overcrowded

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

In my area i can detect 41 different AP, almost every channels are in use and there is no way to avoid channel overlapping. i try to choose the standard channels (1,6,11) and keep having slow internet at high usage hours (8am - 1am). I've changed the ch to 13 and start to get a better performance and speed.

So why is this happening, is my router broken, is the high number of devices in channels 1,611 that slows down my speed. or something else?

Comment: There are way too many AP in your area.  When you have all of those devices are in use, there is no room for your signal.  You would have to shield the inside of your house to block all the other signals out, or go wired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too many wifi signals in your area will have an impact on the speed you can get from your wireless network as they need to share the frequency to communicate. Like you have done already, try to select the channel that has the less number of AP that you can see but at the same time staying on channel 1, 6 or 11 is usually preferable (not sure about 13 but it must be good if you see an improvement).

You can also use a tool like [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/) to help you select the best channel available in your area.

Another solution, if your AP and all your devices support it, would be to switch to the 5 GHz band. It is not necessarily better in theory than the 2.4 GHz band because the range is usually shorter, but it may be better in practice because it is usually way less congested than the 2.4 GHz band.

Comment: i totally forgot i can change from 2.4 to 5 that really help, thanks